# Bloquear acesso direto a arquivos e diretórios

Tags: htaccess

Bom, minha dúvida é simples:

Como posso bloquear o acesso direto a arquivos e diretórios do meu site? Por exemplo, evitar que o usuário acesse o link: `www.meusite.com/img` e obtenha a lista de imagens, ou `/js` e obtenha os arquivos JS, e assim por diante.

Hoje eu possuo um arquivo `index` em branco em cada pasta, o que "bloqueia" o acesso, ou melhor dizer, a visualização.

Eu tentei utilizar o `htaccess` para criar esse bloqueio, algo assim:

```
<Directory  ~ "\">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</Directory>
```

Porém estou obtendo bloqueio total, nem mesmo a navegação ao site é permitida. A única outra configuração que possuo em meu `htaccess` é o `rewrite` para melhorar a `url` do site. Como estou trabalhando com as rotas em `AngularJs`, o código abaixo serve para remover o `/#/` que é adicionado.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index.html$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Como posso obter o resultado? Pois já visualizei alguns sites que ao acessar a pasta, obtemos o resultado de "Forbiden access" que, acredito eu, seja o processo mais correto a ser feito.

Ou... Qual o real propósito/lógica que devo ter nesse quesito?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A opção que você procura é essa:

```
Options -Indexes
```

Pode por direto nos `.htaccess` (se estiver habilitado esse override no Apache).

Exemplo de configuração com `Directory`, em vez de `.htaccess`:

```
<Directory /caminho> 
    Options -Indexes 
</Directory>
```

Documentação (en):

> https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/sections.html#file-and-web

Comment: Em `/caminho` qual devo especificar? O meu arquivo htaccess está na raiz do servidor `/public_html` e precisa estar ali para que o rewrite com o AngularJs funcione. Tentei nomear algumas pastas, mas todos me retornam com erro 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: no .htaccess nao precisa de caminho, é só o `Options -Indexes` mesmo, o caminho é só se usar na config do apache

Comment: A sim, perfeito! As soluções que achei eram sempre muito complexas, com denominação dos diretórios e arquivos que desejávamos bloquear ou permitir o acesso e sempre retornava algum erro ou bloqueava o acesso total. Não imaginei que fosse tão simples. Obrigado!