# Como bloquear acesso a uma pasta em servidor local com PHP?

Tags: php

Estou criando um sistema interno, ele roda através do Xampp em um servidor Windows Server e possui uma pasta chamada pdfs, gostaria de saber se é possível bloquear o acesso dos usuários do **SISTEMA WEB** que estou criando nesta pasta.

o nome do pdf codificado ficaria na base de dados para exibir esse pdf quando necessário, mas não gostaria que os usuários vissem todos pdfs dentro desta pasta se colocar a url no navegador.

Comment: No windows explorer, selecione a pasta clique com botão direito->Propriedades->Segurança

Comment: talvez esse link te ajude
**https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/142656/bloquear-acesso-direto-a-arquivos-e-diret%C3%B3rios**